# .js method "undefined" in a jsp <script> block even though .js file included?

Tags: javascript, function, jsp, undefined

I have this code in a jsMethods.js file:

```
function openPopup(url, name) {
    var options = 'height=650px, width=1050px, scrollbars=no, resizable=yes, toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no';
    window.open(url,name,options);
}
```

and then, I have a .jsp file trying to access this code, but I get an error that says "**'openPopup' is undefined**". Here is the code in my .jsp file:

```
<%@ page import="[some imports here]"%>
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ include file="[some jspf files included here]" %>

<%@ page import="[some more imports here]" %>

<%@ taglib prefix="bean" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-bean" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="html" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-html" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="logic" uri="http://struts.apache.org/tags-logic" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="i18n" uri="/WEB-INF/tld/i18n.tld" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="display" uri="http://displaytag.sf.net" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>

<bean:define [some code] />     

<style>
.hiddenColumn{
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="ISO-8859-1" src="<html:rewrite page='/js/jsMethods.js'/>"></script>  // the path is correct

<script type="text/javascript">        
function myFunction(id, type) { 

    if (type == '3') {
        // PROBLEM - METHOD NOT FOUND ???
        openPopup('<html:rewrite page="/app/tasks/"/>' + id, '');
    }
}
</script>

<%@ include file="[a jspf file included here]"%>

<div id="page">
<html:form action="blabla.do" method="GET">    

    <%@ include file="[a jspf file included here]"%>

    <div id="page-body">
// the page body in which myFunction is called
```

Why is the function openPopup not accessed? I've checked with other .jsp in the project and this is exactly the way they import .js files in the .jsp files. Please, help...

Comment: Did you checked your *Network* tab on the console to see if the browser downloaded and included your script file correctly?

Comment: Agreed - you need to do some client side debug.

Comment: May be your javascript file didn't get downloaded in browser due to wrong file path. Check in you browser if the javascript file is downloaded or not.

Comment: I checked the Network tab when loading the jsp page, and after error - and it's empty. Is it normal? (never used this tab before :))

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got it. Silly thing - the cache was not cleared. After clearing it, it loaded the .js file correctly. Thanks for your help anyway ;)